# How to output exception information in log file with log4php?

Tags: php, exception, logging, log4php

I have set up [log4php](http://logging.apache.org/log4php/) to log to a file using the [LoggerAppenderRollingFile](http://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/appender/appender.html#LoggerAppenderRollingFile) appender and the [LoggerLayoutTTCC](http://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/appender/layout.html#LoggerLayoutTTCC) layout. When I log an exception, however, it doesn't display the exception details such as the stack trace like I'm used to seeing in log4net.

I've had a quick look through the code and it looks like the [LoggerAppenderMongoDB](http://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/appender/appender.html#LoggerAppenderMongoDB) has support for displaying exceptions with the [`formatThrowable` method](http://logging.apache.org/log4php/apidocs/log4php/appenders/LoggerAppenderMongoDB.html#formatThrowable), but I don't see anything similar in the other appenders.

I feel like I am missing something obvious. Is there something that I need to configure in order to print these details to the log file? Do I need to create a custom LoggerAppender class? Or can these be done with a different layout or a custom renderer?

Answer (score 2):

FYI, now that `LoggerLayoutTTCC` is deprecated, you can use [LoggerLayoutPattern](http://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/layouts/pattern.html) with a better format string to include exceptions.

```
<layout class="LoggerLayoutPattern">
   <param name="conversionPattern" value="%d{m/d/y H:i:s,u} [%t] %p %c %x - %m %newline%throwable" />
</layout>

<!-- %newline%throwable is the important part -->
```

See the Logging Exceptions section of the docs: http://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/layouts/pattern.html#Logging_exceptions

Answer (score 1):

You should use PHP set_exception_handler function and wrap log4php using this function.
check it out at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php

```
function exception_handler($exception) {
```

$log->debug($exception->getMessage());
}

set_exception_handler('exception_handler');

Answer (score 1):

I've come to the same conclusion: it looks like log4php only does something with the `$throwable` parameter in the `LoggerAppenderMongoDB.php` appender.

The `LoggerAppenderFile` base class relies on the layout, `LoggerLayoutTTCC`, to format the message (as would be expected). That class has a method `ignoresThrowable()`, which returns true. Although this method does not appear to be called, it does mildly communicate that the authors did not seem to intend to take any note of the error.

I have added my own layout class that extends LoggerLayoutTTCC and overrides format()

```
    class LoggerLayoutTTCCWithException extends LoggerLayoutTTCC
    {
        public function format(LoggerLoggingEvent $event) {
            $format = parent::format($event);

            $throwableInfo = $event->getThrowableInformation();
            if ($throwableInfo === null) {
                return $format;
            }

            $renderer = new LoggerRendererException();
            return $format . $renderer->render($throwableInfo->getThrowable());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure out why the original file name and line number was not logged by **log4php** when an exception is thrown. It turned out that my custom `exception_handler` class was only logging the exception message (by doing `$exception->getMessage()`), which does not contain the file name nor the line number. All I to do is concatenate that info: `$exception->getFile()` and `$exception->getLine()`:

```
public function exception_handler ($exception) {
        $logger = Logger9::create();
        $logger->info($exception->getMessage()." ".$exception->getFile()." ".$exception->getLine());
}
```

Don't forget to register the custom handler:

```
@set_exception_handler(array($this, 'exception_handler'));
```